# How to get declared and inherited members from TypeInfo

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, .net-core

In the [new Reflection API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api/), the `TypeInfo.Declared*` properties are the right way to access the members (fields, properties, methods, etc) declared on a type. However, these properties do not include members inherited from a base class.

The old `TypeInfo.GetRuntime*()` methods return both declared and inherited members, but are not available on all platforms, including .NET Core.

How do I get a list of declared *and* inherited members with the new API?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wrote a set of small extension methods that provide this functionality:

```
public static class TypeInfoAllMemberExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> GetAllConstructors(this TypeInfo typeInfo)
        => GetAll(typeInfo, ti => ti.DeclaredConstructors);

    public static IEnumerable<EventInfo> GetAllEvents(this TypeInfo typeInfo)
        => GetAll(typeInfo, ti => ti.DeclaredEvents);

    public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(this TypeInfo typeInfo)
        => GetAll(typeInfo, ti => ti.DeclaredFields);

    public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetAllMembers(this TypeInfo typeInfo)
        => GetAll(typeInfo, ti => ti.DeclaredMembers);

    public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetAllMethods(this TypeInfo typeInfo)
        => GetAll(typeInfo, ti => ti.DeclaredMethods);

    public static IEnumerable<TypeInfo> GetAllNestedTypes(this TypeInfo typeInfo)
        => GetAll(typeInfo, ti => ti.DeclaredNestedTypes);

    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(this TypeInfo typeInfo)
        => GetAll(typeInfo, ti => ti.DeclaredProperties);

    private static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(TypeInfo typeInfo, Func<TypeInfo, IEnumerable<T>> accessor)
    {
        while (typeInfo != null)
        {
            foreach (var t in accessor(typeInfo))
            {
                yield return t;
            }

            typeInfo = typeInfo.BaseType?.GetTypeInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

This should be super easy to use. Calling `typeInfo.GetAllProperties()`, for example, will return all of the `DeclaredProperties` of the current type and any base types, all the way up the inheritance tree.

I'm not imposing any ordering here, so if you need to enumerate members in a specific order, you may have to tweak the logic.

---

Some simple tests to demonstrate:

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void Get_all_fields()
    {
        var fields = typeof(TestDerived).GetTypeInfo().GetAllFields();

        Assert.True(fields.Any(f => f.Name == "FooField"));
        Assert.True(fields.Any(f => f.Name == "BarField"));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Get_all_properties()
    {
        var properties = typeof(TestDerived).GetTypeInfo().GetAllProperties();

        Assert.True(properties.Any(p => p.Name == "FooProp"));
        Assert.True(properties.Any(p => p.Name == "BarProp"));
    }
}

public class TestBase
{
    public string FooField;

    public int FooProp { get; set; }
}

public class TestDerived : TestBase
{
    public string BarField;

    public int BarProp { get; set; }
}
```

These extension methods are compatible with both desktop .NET 4.5+ and .NET Core.

Comment: How do you get the value of the fields/declared members?

Comment: @alperc You can use more reflection to get the value of a field. Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197004/3191599